# How to choose a Spring @Query annotation to suit the DB (e.g. HSQLDB, Postgres)?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Say I have this annotated Java code:

```
@Transactional
public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, Long> {

@Query("from Event where path like ?1% and date(start_time)=CURRENT_DATE")
Stream<Event> findAllChildrenToday(String path);
```

This works for Postgres. However, when running unit tests I want to use an in-memory database such as HSQLDB. Unfortunately the SQL date(...) command doesn't work on HSQLDB, so I really need something that changes query according to the database like the following in which I've made up an imaginary "db=" tag:

```
@Query(db="Postgres", "from Event where path like ?1% and date(start_time)=CURRENT_DATE")
@Query(db="HSQLDB", "from Event where path like ?1% and start_time >= CURRENT_DATE and (start_time < CURRENT_DATE + 1)")
Stream<Event> findAllChildrenToday(String path);
```

How do I do this for real?

I'm not too familiar with Spring so please be fairly detailed in your answers. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to accept/upvote answers that helped you...

Answer (score 0):

You can make the following trick with [Spring profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html):

```java
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface EventRepo extends JpaRepository<Event, Long> {
    Stream<Event> findAllChildrenToday(String path);
}

@Profile("postgres")
public interface PostgresRepo extends EventRepo {
    @Override 
    @Query(/* a postgres specific query */)
    Stream<Event> findAllChildrenToday(String path);
}

@Profile("hsqldb")
public interface HsqldbRepo extends EventRepo {
    @Override
    @Query(/* a hsqldb specific query */)
    Stream<Event> findAllChildrenToday(String path);
}
```

Then in your service (or controller):

```java
@Service
public class EventService {

    @Autowired
    private EventRepo eventRepo;

    //...
}
```

In the `application.properties` file you set 'postgres' profile (this profile will be used by default in the production):

```
spring.profiles.active=postgres
```

And in your IDE you set 'hsqldb' profile: `-Dspring.profiles.active=hsqldb` (as JVM option).

Thanks to this the repo injection will depend on the used Spring profile.